# how to add a new function for a class which is created previous?

Tags: python, class, function

Just like the title said.
For example:
I have a class like this:

```
class NewClass():
    def func1():
        .....
```

then I want to add a new function into this class when program file running.
just like reassign a new value to the attribute of the class.
e.g.

```
NewClass.a = 3
```

Comment: Why do you need to add it while it is _running_ rather than in the source code?

Comment: This does not sound correct..if possible can you 'edit' your answer and provide a bit of context about what your doing and maybe we can help you get the outcome you want without editing a running program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a function to the class type itself, you can just assign it, making sure to include the argument for the self-reference passed:

```
>>> class Quz(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = "A"
...
>>> def qux(self):
...     print self.a
...
>>> Quz.qux = qux
>>> q = Quz()
>>> q.qux()
A
```

---

You can use `types.MethodType()` to create a bound instance method if you only want to add the function to a single instance of the class:

```
>>> import types
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = "A"
...
>>> def bar(self):
...     print self.a
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar = types.MethodType(bar, f, Foo)
>>> f.bar()
A
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same process as adding an attribute of a non function type:

For the overall class:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   pass
>>> Foo.baz = lambda self: "Foobaz"
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.baz()
'Foobaz'
```

**EDIT**:

Here's something *not* to do, unless you are gloriously lazy, and are aware of and do not care about the consequences that Amber points out in her comment below.

For an instance:

```
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> bar.biz = lambda: "barbiz"
>>> bar.biz()
'barbiz'
```

Comment: Just assigning a function does not bind it to the instance, and thus the function will not get a reference to the instance when it's called.

Comment: True, that's why I threw the second bit - `self` is that reference.  The question was a bit ambiguous, so I thought they may have been monkeypatching an entire class.

Comment: If you fix the first part (for instances), I'll take off the downvote.

Comment: As you wish.  Not because you downvoted though, just because you're right.